# Photo taken without geotag on iPhone Xs despite Location services and wifi being on

Tags: iphone, photos.app

Some photos taken with my iPhone Xs have geotags above the images, and some do not. These photos were all taken in the same location, with the same wifi. I never turned off "location services" for the camera. Why could this be happening?